# Деплой на Github при помощи appveyor

Tags: c#, .net, git, развертывание, appveyor

Хотелось бы попробовать на открытом проекте деплой на GitHub. Начал пробовать appveyor.com. На самом GitHub в [репозитории](https://github.com/Ledrunning/TinnyMonitor) с проектом добавил файл appveyor.yml со следующим содержанием

```
image: Visual Studio 2017

before_build:
- nuget restore
- choco install opencover.portable
- choco install codecov

build:
 project: TinnyClock.sln
 verbosity: minimal

artifacts:
- path: deploy\TinnyMonitor.exe
  name: TinnyMonitor
```

Делаю билд в appveyor, после чего делаю deploy -> получаю следующее. 
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В релизе на самом GitHub появляются архивы, в них просто запакованный проект Visual Studio. Нет exe файла... Что необходимо для создания в релизе exe файла?

Comment: artifacts - это артефакты на самом appveyor, а судя по текстовке - вы могли неправильно написать путь, где искать файлы.

Comment: Это в настройках указать путь? Где физически у меня на ПК  они лежат?

Comment: Все получилось.